# empty openCL program throws deprecation warning

Tags: c++, opencl

I downloaded the AMD APP 3.0 SDK and as soon as I include `#include <CL/cl.hpp>` into my cpp it throws deprecation warnings:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\amd app sdk\3.0\include\cl\cl.hpp(4240): warning 
     C4996: 'clCreateSampler': was declared deprecated
```

and many more.

Am I doing something wrong? I feel uncomfortable starting to play with openCL having so many warnings already before writing a single line of useful code.

Comment: Why not just get used to it?

Comment: Khronos recently put cl.hpp on github, so you could fix it yourself! https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-Headers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here is that `cl.hpp` is for OpenCL 1.X platforms, but the rest of AMD's SDK supports OpenCL 2.0. The `clCreateSampler` function was deprecated in OpenCL 2.0.

Khronos have released an OpenCL 2.X version of the C++ bindings - `cl2.hpp` - which is what you should use if you wish to target OpenCL 2.0 devices using the C++ API. It may not have propagated to the vendor SDKs yet, but you can get the latest version [directly from Khronos](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-CLHPP/releases). To target OpenCL 2.0 with this header, you would include it like this:

```
#define CL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 200
#include <CL/cl2.hpp>
```

If you wish to target OpenCL 1.2 platforms instead, you just need to change the value of the `CL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION_MACRO`:

```
#define CL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 120
#include <CL/cl2.hpp>
```

(this will suppress the deprecation warnings that you previously received)

You could still use the 1.X header (`cl.hpp`) for 1.X platforms; you just need to make it clear that the deprecation warnings are not an issue for you:

```
#define CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_2_APIS
#include <CL/cl.hpp>
```

Comment: Switching from `cl.hpp` to `cl2.hpp` header opened a `LNK2005` error on my Intel OpenCL SDK: `enum cl::QueueProperties __cdecl cl::operator|(enum cl::QueueProperties,enum cl::QueueProperties) ...<mangling>... already defined in opencl_ops-tester.obj`

Comment: @PatrizioBertoni This issue should have been fixed a few months ago, are you using the latest cl2.hpp available here? https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-CLHPP/releases/tag/v2.0.9